# Quartz .NET 2.x can I configure scheduler with different thread pools

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

i am new to Quartz .NET. I'm using version 2.6. 
I have 2 kind of job, low and high priority. I'd want a thread pool only for high priority job. 
Is there a way to configure the scheduler to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd want a thread pool only for high priority job.

The ThreadPool provides a set of Threads for Quartz to use when executing Jobs. When there is a new job, it should be executed in the thread from quartz thread pool and this thread could come only from Quartz Thread Pool.

How many thread pools you may have: each Quartz scheduler instance will only allow you to create one thread pool and all the jobs in this scheduler instance will be run in this pool.

And so you may create many Quartz scheduler instances, and thus separate your jobs.

---

Note: Thread pool size, threads system priority, and pool implementation could be [modified/replaced](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool.html). To provide own implementation, you need a class derived from [`IThreadPool` interface](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/SPI/IThreadPool.cs#L47)

```
    /// Execute the given <see cref="Task" /> in the next
    /// available <see cref="Thread" />.
    bool RunInThread(Func<Task> runnable);
```

From [docs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/configuration-resource-usage-and-scheduler-factory.html): Quartz ships with a simple (but very satisfactory) thread pool named `Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool`. This `IThreadPool` implementation simply maintains a fixed set of threads in its pool - never grows, never shrinks. But it is otherwise quite robust and is very well tested - as nearly everyone using Quartz uses this pool.